# Url rewriting SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint

I want to do Url rewriting in sharepoint . If anyone is having any idea how to achieve this in sharepoint.

Thr url rewrite would be like..
/www.ABC.com instead of www.ABC.com/pages/default.aspx
and also like ww.ABC.com/ED.html  instead of www.ABC.com/ED.aspx

Thanks,
PS

Comment: I still didn't get the answer of my question thats y I didn't marked it as answered...last post is still mine and I m having some issues

Answer (score 3):

You'll need to implement an `IHttpModule` and to register it in your web.config /configuration/system.web/httpModules element, *before* `SPRequest` declaration.

Good luck!

**EDIT:** This article explains what you need to know: [A Complete URL Rewriting Solution for ASP.NET 2.0](http://www.simple-talk.com/content/print.aspx?article=357). You can skip XML parametrization code.

Comment: Thanks Rubens for the reply but I was thinking to hear some more help related to it as I know I hv to do this by creating httpmodule and aslso making changes in the config sections....but I didn't get any gud link or article about sharepoint url rewriting....

Comment: And probably you wont find more data; remove Sharepoint from equation and to write a IHttpModule implementation; _later_ add it to Sharepoint

Comment: Spot on.  I created a commercial product that does exactly what the orignal poster asks but it is not available yet.  This becomes significantly more challenging in a farm with more than one web front end (WFE) server.

Comment: THanks for the reply guys....
I found some blogs related to asp.net url rewriting and they are using context.beginrequest . Could you tell me what modifications I need to make as far as sharepoint is concerned.I m new to sharepoint so don't know how to do this thing in sharepoint.

I found this blog
http://www.simple-talk.com/dotnet/asp.net/a-complete-url-rewriting-solution-for-asp.net-2.0/
and I wanted to know if i can use same with sharepoint rewriting

Comment: under sharepoint, you just need to add your httpmodule BEFORE SPRequest on your web.config

Comment: I am confused...k i m using httpapplication.beginrequest but what you are saying is i need to use spbeginrequest ? while I m creating my httpmodule in visual studio? I knw i need to add httpmodule in web.config main thing is how to create and what to put in that httpmodule ....could you tell me in detail as I guess you have solution for this problem?

Comment: Thanks Rubens :-) ........I have been trying to implement this link only as this is the only closest bet I also found on net....but getting 404 not found. Did you try that in sharepoint?